# Any solution using SMS to restart / reboot the router / server?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, sms

Given

1. home network: VPN server behind NAT of a router
2. office network: VPN client to access home resources

Problem

1. Either router/ VPN server is hung
2. Unable to restart/ reboot them through networking
3. Two locations are far apart, physically unable to restart/ reboot
   them

Is there any way to restart/ reboot them by sending a SMS message to a home-made SMS server to do so?

Comment: I hate to say that but your best bet would be to use a hardware solution, the only one I know of is [this one](http://www.my-plug.fr/). There is no easy to use software for receiving SMS through a GSM modem and any scripts you would make that use AT commands to drive the modem are "hacky" and may fail you when you most need them.

Comment: Rather than futz w/ SMS to reboot the router why not use something that can reboot it automatically?  When it stops responding to pings for example.  I use these:  http://www.digital-loggers.com/lpc.html.  It'll also give a web gui (when your router is UP) that you can use to control up to seven other devices.  I use them for routers (auto ping) and I use them to reboot clients' cable boxes and other lock-up-prone devices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want something along lines of the many network monitoring solutions a la nagios, where if a ping fails, an action will be taken:

Ping something on the lan on the other side of the VPN
Ping the other routers VPN IP
Ping the other routers wan IP

Ping the local default gateway (router)
Ping the next hop along the isps network to give to ISP in case you need to report it to them
Reboot the local firewall and gateway

Is the sms connectivity in case of an outage? You can use a clearwire or other type of wireless circuit as a backup, these are pretty reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this little neat tech. It's a simple remote power adapter with gsm module inside. You can call on it to toggle power, as well as send commands via sms. Also has memory for 5 numbers, so it's secure enough. It's roughly $20 and does exactly what is needed.
Ideal to reboot frozen router.
If you want to safely shut down your server/pc, just configure your backup power source to do it on power outage, and plug it in this adapter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1c_k1xaP9s

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CXyK.jpg)